# how to create st1 storageclass within a cluster deployed by kops?

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I deployed a cluster with kops, and then I listed the storage class:

```
kubectl get storageclass --all-namespaces
NAME            PROVISIONER             AGE
default         kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   2h
gp2 (default)   kubernetes.io/aws-ebs   2h
```

I want to make a PVC of type `st1`, how shall I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create storage classes like any other Kubernetes resource. For the `st1` storage class, the following should work:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: st1
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: st1
```

You can find more information on storage classes [in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes), and also in particular on using the [`kubenetes.io/aws-ebs` provisioner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws).

If you then want to [dynamically provision a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/#using-dynamic-provisioning) using that class, use the `storageClassName: st1` property when creating a PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: your-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: st1
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Gi
```